# How can I output the source code of a function in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to get the source code of my type script function ** in type script **.

This typescript code

```
var fn = function (a:number, b:number) {
   return a + b;
};

console.log("Code: " + fn);
```

prints the java script version of the function,

```
Code: function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }
```

but I'd like to have the original type script code, if possible with type information. Especially when using `this` inside the function, the translated and output js code is less beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible unless you write your own string literal containing the Typescript source code. Typescript is compiled to Javascript, so this is what is actually running when you run your script:

```js
"use strict";
var fn = function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
};
console.log("Code: " + fn);
```

As you can see, there are no type annotations here, so there is absolutely no way this code could print those type annotations to the console.

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/G4QwTgBAZgdhC80CuMDGAXAlgezgChAC4YkBbAIwFMwAaCc4sqsASggG8AoCHsS9JGDggIAanoBuTgF8pnVLgDO2ADaUAdCuwBzPACIAwtgAmlQhD1joMFlKA)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, but maybe you want to use source-maps?